# Is there a web part to display all subsites with description?

Tags: web-part

I am looking for a way (via web part?) to display all sub-sites of a site collection with output similar to output you see under "Sites & Workspaces" (under All Site Content)...

I know there is a way to use SOAP webservice as a data source and then add it to a web page via SP Designer, but I was hoping there is a web part that is a bit more customizable...

I'm using SharePoint Foundation 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Data View Web Part (DVWP) using either the Webs Web Service *or* DataSourceMode="Webs" is a great way to go. Easy to customize and style. If you spent most of a day looking for something, then you could have already been done!

---

//EDIT
As Laurie points out, you generally build and style a DVWP using SharePoint Designer. DVWPs have been available in every version of SharePoint going back to 2003.

You add a DVWP to the page using Insert / Data View on the ribbon in SharePoint Designer 2010.
//EDIT

Comment: @Marc D Anderson - Marc, I saw referneces about DVWP while looking on the web, but is this web part available on 2010 SharePoint Foundation? I certainly can't see it anywhere (not in Gallery either)...

Comment: The Data View Web Part can only be added through SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Laurie, why? DataViewWebPart is public. Can you give us some proof links? I'm sure you can add any of standard webparts using either XML elements with AllUsersWebPart or sharepoint object model and SPLimitedWebPartManager.

Comment: I think Laurie meant that DVWPs can only be created in SharePoint Designer (well, and probably in VS too, IDK, I don't use the product).  Once created, the web part can be exported and imported to other pages via the UI.

Comment: And the good thing about using a DWVP and the web service, it will automatically security trim the results based on what the current logged in user has access to.

Comment: What I meant was the DVWP is not one of the web parts that the user can insert through the browser, where zam6ak was looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a web part for WSS 3.0. From the screenshot, it looks like the author just iterates through each SPWeb and writes out a link using the subsite.Url and subsite.Title.

http://sharepointnavigation.codeplex.com/releases/view/9462

Using Webs.asmx via SharePoint Designer, as you suggested is probably a better option.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this and got a bunch of errors...I actually spent most of the day yesterday combing Internet (especially CodePlex) looking for a suitable web part :)...

Answer (score 0):

Activating the publishing features will allow you to use a webpart called "Table of Contents". Publishing features need SharePoint Standard Edition. This will let you display the contents below the current site in many different ways. A list of webparts can be found here:

http://www.wssdemo.com/Pages/webparts.aspx

But activating publishing features comes with some restrictions. For instance, the site can not be saved as a template, so think twice before activating on any random site.

Comment: @GeekDotNet - is this web part available on SP 2010 Foundation? I need something that will work with Foundation....

Comment: No it isn't, the table of contents is part of the publishing infrastructure which Foundations does not have.

Comment: @PirateEric Thanks...I need web part/solution for SPF...

Answer (score 0):

We have a legacy web part from Coras I believe called Site Workspace Viewer that does this.  I believe it was originally created for SPS 2003 and it still works in 2007.  I don't know if it would work in 2010 (we haven't started upgrade testing yet).  Unfortunately I can't find much reference to the product anymore, it was purchased and installed before I came into this position.